# Most appropriate pronoun to refer to something that claims to be human

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> ... prevent claimed users (**which**/**who** are in fact bots)...

In the above sentence, what's the most appropriate choice to refer to the users that are in fact bots? I think, `which` is correct one, however I'm afraid of grammatical mismatch. Of course, using `that` can solve the problem, by the way.

Comment: *Who*, naturally, should be the pronoun: "claimed users" are (real or fake) humans, that is, either humans, or bots emulating humans, and thus **"who", in scare quotes** if needed. In the given sentence and its context, the image is one of a "user" without the distract of their exactly technical nature.

Comment: Why not "that"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use either and it would be acceptable. However, you already anthropomorphized them by using the verb *claim*, so it would be consistent to use *who* to refer to them. If you changed that phrase to something less active, such *seemingly human users*, it would then be more appropriate to use *which*.

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting. I am not 100% sure of my answer but just throwing it out here.

It depends what the noun of the sentence is or more specifically what they first of are.

Are they before anything Users or Bots?

In my opinion, bots are users too and users are people so by extension; bots are people too and for people the correct pronoun would be "Who".

So personally, I would use who. But with that said, which can work as well if you analyse it differently.

Comment: That better be posted as a comment.

Comment: Saying "all users are people therefore bots are people" is faulty logic. If a bot can be a user and a person can be a user, it follows that people can be users and bots can be users, not that bots can be people.